# Run maven plugin before resolving dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to run a maven plugin *before* the system would resolve all dependencies?
Or at least, run it, *even* if not all dependencies have been made?
Or even if a `DependencyResolutionException` is thrown?

Comment: You can do this on the command line, like `mvn some:goal install`, then `some:goal` runs first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was thinking something that wouldn't have to explicitly state the goal at the command line, but to exist already in the pom file. So maybe this is not possible?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Can you explain the problem by a use case?

Comment: @khmarbaise There is a kind of dependency, which could not be resolved unfortunately through the usual mechanism, but it needs to run specific code for that first. So the idea was, instead of creating something like a shell wrapper, if it is possible to handle this by maven itself.

Comment: This sounds like you should write a plugin for Maven which handles that. Apart from that I would put such dependency into a repository manager etc. and clean up that dependency ? cause that sounds strange...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, that's what I thought, of course, to write a plugin. But, since the dependencies are handled before loading plugins, I was thinking if there is a way to force something beforehand.